# Select query does not complete when using offset-fetch

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have implemented pagination in a web application using Linq, the query generated by Linq looks similar to this one:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID_PLAZO] AS [ID_PLAZO], 
    LTRIM(RTRIM([Extent1].[ID_EXPEDIENTE])) AS [ID_EXPEDIENTE], 
    [Extent1].[ID_TIPO_PLAZO] AS [ID_TIPO_PLAZO], 
    [Extent1].[FECHA_INICIO] AS [FECHA_INICIO], 
    [Extent1].[FECHA_FIN] AS [FECHA_FIN], 
    [Extent1].[FECHA_EJECUCION_INICIO] AS [FECHA_EJECUCION_INICIO], 
    [Extent1].[FECHA_EJECUCION_FIN] AS [FECHA_EJECUCION_FIN]
    FROM   [dbo].[AESEG_PLAZO] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[AESEG_EXPEDIENTE] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ID_EXPEDIENTE] = [Extent2].[ID_EXPEDIENTE]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[SAS_CONVOCATORIA] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[ID_CONVOCATORIA] = [Extent3].[CONV_ID_CONVOCATORIA]
    WHERE ([Extent3].[CONV_PREFIJO_EXP] LIKE '%AC15%' ESCAPE '~') OR ([Extent3].[CONV_DESCRIPCION] LIKE '%AC15%' ESCAPE '~')
ORDER BY [Extent1].[ID_PLAZO] ASC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

The query does work and returns 10 results in less than a second, but if I fetch 5 rows it does not end.

I have noticed that the execution plan is a bit different in those cases but I am not an SQL expert. Do you know how to solve this or why is this happening?

**fetch 10 rows**

[image: fetch 10 rows]

**fetch 5 rows**

[image: fetch 5 rows]

Comment: It seems that you have solved this by your own following some blog. so you should not post it as edit instead post it as an answer and click tick to accept it as an answer so anyone can understand. For convenience, I have placed your edit an answer. Accept it if it solved your question

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, It's the first time I post here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is in the **ESCAPE '~'** part. Finally, i used this approach to generate a query without that, and it works fine and faster.

http://jendaperl.blogspot.com.es/2011/02/like-in-linq-to-entities.html